# Triggering an event when a ReactNative app is opened

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Does anyone know how to trigger an event whenever a reactnative app is opened? eg. to refresh data whenever a user opens the app again.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Need to use this. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstateios.html#content

Comment: I think this page changed. What did you do?

Answer (score -1):

Go to that file where navigation starts from.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Root } from './config/router';

    class Index extends Component {
        componentWillMount(){
             //your event function code
}
        render() {
            return <Root />;
        }
    }

export default Index;

Here Root contains all screens where navigation starts.
```